# Finding mean and SD of 2 parts of a whole

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, compositional-data

I am putting together a review/meta-analysis of body composition in children. The data I will analyze consists of measures of fat-mass (FM) and fat-free-mass (FFM), which when summed  equal total mass. While most papers report the means and SDs for FM and FFM, which is what I want, every so often I get a paper that reports the mean and SD of total mass, and a mean and SD of %FM (i.e. FM/(FM+FFM)).

My question: Can I calcuate the mean and SD of FM and FFM, given I have the mean and SD of total mass, and the mean and SD of FM/(FM+FFM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a partial answer, adressing one of your questions.

Generally, for probability distributions you have:

$$
E(X+Y) = E(X)+E(Y)
$$
and
V
$$
V(X+Y) = V(X)+V(Y) + 2\text{Cov}(X,Y)
$$
with E and V being the expectation and variance respectively ($SD = \sqrt{V}$).

For you, this means the mean of the sum is just the sums of the means (so you can get it). For the SD of the sum you also need the covariance or correlation between the FM and FFM. One might use sensible guesses to get realistic lower and upper bounds. Your question regarding FM/(FM+FFM) is much more complicated.

I am not even sure that it is possible without knowing the exact distributions. There is an approximate solution using the delta method:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables. But you also require the covariance for that.

Comment: Thanks. There is no way I'll get the covariances, but even just the means can be helpful, given I have sample sizes and can make pretty good guesses about the variances given the other data I have. At the very least you have kept me from hitting my head against the wall all day trying to work this out.